pcieport AER messages spamming, can't install Ubuntu Server
First of all, I cleaned my laptop. It's not really old, but I didn't really ever use it because I have a better one, and this one just sits on my shelf. I wanted to use it as a home server, so I cleaned it and booted it up on Windows. I backed up my stuff, and everything was working great. I installed Ubuntu Server, SSH'd into it from my desktop, and everything was good.
I ran apt update and apt upgrade, and after a reboot, it started spamming the TTY with AER error codes (see picture), it was also using a lot of CPU, the process was something along the lines of systemd-journald. Two iterations of the error, pcieport and rt18723be . I tried some things in the terminal, but nothing worked, so I decided to reinstall Ubuntu Server using the same USB and the same ISO, however when I tried installing it random commands popped up everywhere. After a while, I landed on a bare TTY that didn't even work and only showed keyboard inputs.
I thought maybe the ISO was damaged, but the checksum was fine. I checked the SSD, and it says it's fine. Even booting into an Arch Linux installation ISO gives me these errors.

Error codes that are getting spammed:
rt18723be 0000:03:00.0: AER: Error of this Agent is reported first
pcieport 0000:0:1c:5: AER: Error of this Agent is reported first

